# Understanding「汲ませて」 and 「にっぷん」, assuming that is what was said

Tags: grammar, conjugations, listening

I have a question regarding what is being said in [this video](https://youtu.be/xfScsa1fNkY?t=15m32s).

**First of all, what is being said?**

The following is what I perceived.

> ...水{みず}を**汲{く}ませて**、しっかりと**にっぷん**してから、撃{う}ちます。

In particular, I am uncertain about the parts in bold.

「にっぷん」 is probably just a listening error, as it does not appear in any of my dictionaries. However, I can't seem to hear it as anything else.

Assuming that I heard it correctly, 「汲ませて」 appears to be the causative form of 「汲む」, perhaps meaning something like "to scoop" in this case.

**However, I do not understand why the causative form of the verb is being used**.

From the beginning of the sentence, the subject seems to be the method (of shooting water with your hands).

However, none of the other verbs are in the causative form. Is it because you are "making the hand scoop" water? Would 「汲んで」 also be valid here?

I would appreciate help resolving these questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are hearing both parts wrong.

She says 「水を[含]{ふく}ませて、しっかりと[密封]{みっぷう}してから撃ちます。」

= "You (let your hands) hold water, seal it good and then shoot."

Comment: Thanks! It seems my listening skills still have quite a way to go. :)